# Run job only when changes in directory, where directory is passed in via parallel matrix (Gitlab CI)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

There are a few ways to run jobs only when there are changes in a specific directory (`only`, `rules`, custom logic in a `script` block).  However, I would like to combine this concept with a list of directories inside a parallel matrix, i.e,

```yaml
image: alpine

stages:
- run

my-job:
  stage: run
  rules:
    - changes:
      -  $DIR
  script:
    - echo "In $DIR"
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DIR: path/to/A/*
      - DIR: path/to/B
```

The intention being that `my-job` is only added to the pipeline and run for `path/to/A` when it contains changes, and for `path/to/B` when it contain changes.  Trying this solution, the jobs are never added to the CI -- presumably because  the `rules` are processed before the parallel matrix is.

I do not want to add logic to the `script` block; I want the job to be excluded from the pipeline altogether unless changes in `$DIR` exist.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: There is same issue in Gitlab Official Issues. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363668

Comment: That issue suggests that you *can* do this with `changes` rules. You might be having an issue with variable expansion inside your matrix variable definition though? You might try defining your wildcards like this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#variables-in-ruleschanges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments on the original post, this *should* be possible.

And it is.

The example is not an exact reflection of the code I was using.  In that code, there was a rule being copied in via `extends` that was overwriting the `rules:changes` that I thought was not working properly.

For posterity, here is a related GitLab issue that was given to me in the comments -- the example code there works: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363668

Answer (score 0):

With this code, I manage to create specific jobs for a given `env(TARGET)` *only* if the `terraform/$TARGET/**/*` folder contains modifications:

```
…
terraform format:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - gitlab-terraform fmt
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - TARGET: test
      - TARGET: qa
  environment:
    name: $TARGET
    action: verify
  rules:
    - changes:
        - terraform/$TARGET/**/*
…
```